# Getting all data proper in login post request even though it is not logging and giving error 302

Tags: load, jmeter, performance-testing

I have successfully prepared my load testing plan. But getting issue in login. When I see request details , it is showing all data proper like below  :

```
POST http://www.example.com/

POST data:
--a2ReOOZ8H2Jn8VllGKwVF5gsBVQTsM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__RequestVerificationToken"

  S243d1LaiLCoWFxvtvSDRezOMUNsQDT/S0tGC43izR/YJCSF93omizWyGNk8MmEulIEP/Sxn7490cgKl6K0V3m774Oq9XNyMaQakuc0acKT13e/PmjnJdnAwxcbduM3a8gJVKVC7VNJ59PH7y7ppuE4NQlZC0wtOGMP39llbQgWY66DSYxvcx4tyvVm0h+iK
--a2ReOOZ8H2Jn8VllGKwVF5gsBVQTsM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UserName"

tester
--a2ReOOZ8H2Jn8VllGKwVF5gsBVQTsM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Password"

tester
--a2ReOOZ8H2Jn8VllGKwVF5gsBVQTsM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="RememberMe"

true
--a2ReOOZ8H2Jn8VllGKwVF5gsBVQTsM--


 Cookie Data:
ASP.NET_SessionId=eswnzc1vxvbdeo05mttfdhmj;         __RequestVerificationToken_Lw__=5XeEeIoV+rHtjL465iC3+RZcM15sSwmGpzKijR0uWoQA9AdGH+TigsdKuxaVQlv9AHyQKwVwJ1o4teKDxYgKyHJGwlEFnOn65JNnjIDKlpJVexMBUsrIJzRHUZBdPPhLuVSCtfBvi68yediAYxWbqnXVi9tscY043OcLr/q8OWA=

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 634
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=a2ReOOZ8H2Jn8VllGKwVF5gsBVQTsM;       charset=UTF-8
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)
```

What can be issue in login? I am getting **Response code: 302
Response message: Found** when login.

Answer (score 0):

Finally It is solved by selecting **Implementation = JAVA** in Jmeter.

Reference Link : https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites